# Proof of consistency of OLS estimator under Heteroskedasticity

Tags: least-squares, econometrics, heteroscedasticity, consistency

$\DeclareMathOperator{\pl}{\operatorname{plim}}$

Consider a general linear regression model with heteroskedastic errors
$$
\boldsymbol{y}=\boldsymbol{X}\boldsymbol{\beta}+\boldsymbol{u} \quad \text{with} \quad V(\boldsymbol{u}\vert \boldsymbol{X})=\sigma^2\boldsymbol{\Omega}
$$
where $\boldsymbol{\Omega}$ is an arbitrary positive definite matrix. I want to proof that OLS is consistent under this setting and came up with two approaches:

---

One can express the OLS estimator as:
$$
\boldsymbol{\hat{\beta}}=\boldsymbol{\beta}+(\boldsymbol{X}^\top\boldsymbol{X})^{-1}\boldsymbol{X}^\top\boldsymbol{u}
=\boldsymbol{\beta}+\left(\frac{\boldsymbol{X}^\top\boldsymbol{X}}{n}\right)^{-1}\frac{\boldsymbol{X}^\top\boldsymbol{u}}{n} 
$$
Assuming that $\pl\left(\left(\frac{\boldsymbol{X}^\top\boldsymbol{X}}{n}\right)^{-1}\right)=\boldsymbol{\Sigma}_{\boldsymbol{x}\boldsymbol{x}}^{-1}$ and noticing that $\pl\left(\frac{\boldsymbol{X}^\top\boldsymbol{u}}{n}\right)=\boldsymbol{0}$ yields:
\begin{align*}
\pl(\boldsymbol{\hat{\beta}})&=\boldsymbol{\beta}+\pl\left(\left(\frac{\boldsymbol{X}^\top\boldsymbol{X}}{n}\right)^{-1}\frac{\boldsymbol{X}^\top\boldsymbol{u}}{n}\right)\\
&=\boldsymbol{\beta}+\pl\left(\left(\frac{\boldsymbol{X}^\top\boldsymbol{X}}{n}\right)^{-1}\right)\pl\left(\frac{\boldsymbol{X}^\top\boldsymbol{u}}{n}\right)\\
&=\boldsymbol{\beta}+\boldsymbol{\Sigma}_{\boldsymbol{x}\boldsymbol{x}}^{-1}\boldsymbol{0}\\
&=\boldsymbol{\beta}
\end{align*}

---

Another way to prove this is to note that:
$$
E(\boldsymbol{\hat{\beta}})=E(E(\boldsymbol{\hat{\beta}}\vert\boldsymbol{X}))=\boldsymbol{\beta}
$$
The covariance matrix under heteroskedasticity is given by:
\begin{align*}
V(\boldsymbol{\hat{\beta}}\vert \boldsymbol{X})=\sigma^2(\boldsymbol{X}^\top\boldsymbol{X})^{-1}\boldsymbol{X}^\top\boldsymbol{\Omega}\boldsymbol{X}(\boldsymbol{X}^\top\boldsymbol{X})^{-1}
=\frac{\sigma^2}{n}\left(\frac{\boldsymbol{X}^\top\boldsymbol{X}}{n}\right)^{-1}\left(\frac{\boldsymbol{X}^\top\boldsymbol{\Omega}\boldsymbol{X}}{n}\right)\left(\frac{\boldsymbol{X}^\top\boldsymbol{X}}{n}\right)^{-1}
\end{align*}
Thus, if $\pl\left(\left(\frac{\boldsymbol{X}^\top\boldsymbol{X}}{n}\right)^{-1}\right)=\boldsymbol{\Sigma}_{\boldsymbol{x}\boldsymbol{x}}^{-1}$ and $\pl\left(\frac{\boldsymbol{X}^\top\boldsymbol{\Omega}\boldsymbol{X}}{n}\right)=\boldsymbol{\Sigma}_{\boldsymbol{x}\boldsymbol{\Omega}\boldsymbol{x}}$, then
$$
V(\boldsymbol{\hat{\beta}}\vert \boldsymbol{X}) \rightarrow \boldsymbol{0}
$$
as $n \rightarrow \infty$.

---

Now, my question. I wonder what is the relationship between the conditions $\pl\left(\frac{\boldsymbol{X}^\top\boldsymbol{u}}{n}\right)=\boldsymbol{0}$ and $\pl\left(\frac{\boldsymbol{X}^\top\boldsymbol{\Omega}\boldsymbol{X}}{n}\right)=\boldsymbol{\Sigma}_{\boldsymbol{x}\boldsymbol{\Omega}\boldsymbol{x}}$. In particular, in the second approach one implicitly uses that $\pl\left(\frac{\boldsymbol{X}^\top\boldsymbol{u}}{n}\right)=\boldsymbol{0}$, otherwise $E(\boldsymbol{\hat{\beta}})\neq \boldsymbol{\beta}$, however, I do not see why $\pl\left(\frac{\boldsymbol{X}^\top\boldsymbol{u}}{n}\right)=\boldsymbol{0}$ implies that $\pl\left(\frac{\boldsymbol{X}^\top\boldsymbol{\Omega}\boldsymbol{X}}{n}\right)=\boldsymbol{\Sigma}_{\boldsymbol{x}\boldsymbol{\Omega}\boldsymbol{x}}$. Both approaches seem reasonable to me - please correct me if I am wrong - and consequently both approaches should rely on the same assumptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\DeclareMathOperator{\pl}{\operatorname{plim}}$

Firstly, a review of a simple result ($\bf X$ is nonstochastic):

***Proposition $1:$ (cf. $[\rm I], ~2.5, ~p. 65$)** If $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\mathbf {X^\top\Omega X}}{n}$ is finite, then $\hat{\boldsymbol\beta}$ is consistent.*

In \begin{align}\pl \hat{\boldsymbol\beta}&= \boldsymbol \beta + \lim \left(\frac{\mathbf{X^\top X}}{n}\right)^{-1}\pl \left(\frac{\mathbf X^\top\mathbf u}{n}\right)\tag 1, \label 1\end{align}

$\left(\frac{\mathbf X^\top\mathbf u}{n}\right)$ has mean zero mean and covariance matrix $\sigma^2\left(\frac{\mathbf {X^\top\Omega X}}{n^2}\right)$ which vanishes asymptotically as per the assumption of finiteness of $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\mathbf {X^\top\Omega X}}{n}$ and this subsequently implies $\pl \left(\frac{\mathbf X^\top\mathbf u}{n}\right) = \mathbf 0.$

$\blacksquare$

Now, $$\operatorname{Var}[\hat{\boldsymbol\beta}|\mathbf X] = \frac{\sigma^2}{n}\left(\frac{\mathbf{X^\top X}}{n}\right)^{-1}\left(\frac{\mathbf {X^\top\Omega X}}{n}\right)\left(\frac{\mathbf{X^\top X}}{n}\right)^{-1}\tag 2\label 2.$$

In $\eqref 2,$ well-behaved regressors don't necessarily mean $ \frac{\sigma^2}{n}\left(\frac{\mathbf {X^\top\Omega X}}{n}\right)$ will converge to zero (cf. $[\rm II], ~9.3.2, p. 302 $).

However, (cf. $\rm[II], 9.3.3.,~p. 304$) it would be rather surprising $\left(\frac{\mathbf{X^\top X}}{n}\right)$ converges to a positive-definite matrix, but $\left(\frac{\mathbf {X^\top\Omega X}}{n}\right)$ doesn't.

Finally, consistency, in general, depends on $\bf X$ and $\bf \Omega$ both. As $\rm [III]$ shows,

***Theorem $1.$** If $\mathrm{ (a)}. ~\forall n, ~\lambda_\text{largest}(\Omega)$ is bounded; $\mathrm{(b)}. \lim_{n\to\infty}\lambda_\text{smallest}(\mathbf{X^\top X}) = \infty ,$ then $\hat{\boldsymbol\beta}$ is consistent.*

It follows from the inequality that for nonnegaive definite matrices $\mathbf A,~\mathbf B ,~ \operatorname{tr}(\mathbf{AB})\leq \lambda_\text{largest}(\mathbf A)\operatorname{tr}(\mathbf{B})$ in  that

\begin{align}\operatorname{tr}\left[\left(\mathbf{X^\top X}\right)^{-1}\left(\mathbf {X^\top\Omega X}\right)\left(\mathbf{X^\top X}\right)^{-1}\right] &\leq \operatorname{tr}\left[\mathbf{ X\Omega}\left(\mathbf{X^\top X}\right)^{-2}\mathbf X^\top\right]\\ &\leq \lambda_\text{largest}(\mathbf \Omega)\operatorname{tr}(\mathbf{X^\top X})^{-1}\tag 3\label 3.\end{align}

The rest follows.

$\blacksquare$

---

### References:

$\rm [I]$ Econometrics, *Peter Schmidt,*  Taylor & Francis Group, $1976.$

$\rm [II]$ Econometric Analysis, *William Greene,* Pearson Education, $2018.$

$\rm [III]$ Advanced Econometrics, *Takeshi Amemiya,* Harvard University Press, $1985,$ sec. $6.1.4,$ pp. $184-185.$

Comment: Thank you very much for this brilliant explanation.